# difference between mongos "bind_ip" and "bind_ip_all"

Tags: mongodb

What is the difference between bind_ip and bind_ip_all when running mongos?

I know you can specify a list of ips with bind_ip so what is the point of bind_ip_all?

Comment: Its point is to bind to all interfaces without enumerating them explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

From MongoDB Official documentation

[net.bindIpAll](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.bindIpAll)

> If true, the mongos or mongod instance binds to all IPv4 addresses
>   (i.e. 0.0.0.0). If mongos or mongod starts with net.ipv6 : true,
>   net.bindIpAll also binds to all IPv6 addresses (i.e. ::).
>
> mongos or mongod only supports IPv6 if started with net.ipv6 : true.
>   Specifying net.bindIpAll alone does not enable IPv6 support.
>
> **NOTE**
>
> *net.bindIp and net.bindIpAll are mutually exclusive. Specifying both
>   options causes mongos or mongod to throw an error and terminate.*

Answer (score 0):

With bindIp you can bind particular IP addresses like this,

```
bindIp=[127.0.0.1,11.22.33.44] 
bindIp=0.0.0.0 // This will bind for all IP address (works similar to bindIpAll)
```

Where as **bindIpAll**, just providing this for mongod process will automatically bind to all IP addresses